# Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.50953e-17

Tags: r, economics, mlogit

I am trying to run a `mlogit` in R using a travel diary of ridehailing trips. The dependent variable is solo vs. pool (e.g., UberX vs. UberPOOL) (See screenshot of the data after applying `mlogit.data`. Each person (id) did different numbers of trips. Age and Income are individual-specific variables, "Taxi_type_payment" (how the person paid the ride) is trip-specific, and "DUR" is the duration of the trip.

```r
f <- mFormula(choice ~ DUR | HH_income + Age +Taxi_type_payment | 0)
f1 <- mFormula(choice ~ 0|Taxi_type_payment + HH_income + Age + DUR|0)
ml <- mlogit(f1, data, reflevel="1")
```

`mlogit` runs with mformula `f1` and does not with formula `f`. `f` gives the following error:

```r
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.50953e-17
```

I would appreciate any help to understand why.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The error you get means that you cannot invert the Hessian to get the asymptotic variance covariance matrix, i.e. the determinant of the Hessian is zero. Does the simple model where you only estimate `choice ~ DUR` wihtout anything else in there work?

Comment: @edsandorf thank you. Yes, it does. I now also tried this form that works: binary.ml <- mlogit(choice~ DUR|Age+HH_income+Taxi_type_payment -1, data, reflevel="1") . Honestly, 1) I don't get why the -1 makes the function work. I thought -1 means no intercept; 2) I want to put Taxi_type_payment in the third part of the right side of the equation that is dedicated to alternative spec variables with dedicated coefficient. Yet, if I do it, it gives me the above error again. Do you have any suggestions to make it work?  And, why it cannot invert the Hessian? Thank you.

Comment: The fact that dropping the intercept works, suggests that your model might be over-fitted and that the intercept is perfectly confounded with one of the other included variables. Now, have you specified the problem correctly? You observe 2 types of trips: solo and shared, and based on the diary: what they chose. Wouldn't that make `choice ~ shared + duration | -1` the natural base model? Then you can use interactions between `shared` and your socio-demographics to look at the marginal effects of those on choosing shared?